# Are there any important difference between state and object in the class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me show what i mean:

```js
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prop: 0
    }
  }
  prop = 0;
  
  changeProp = () => {
    this.setState({
      prop: 5
    });
    this.prop = 5
  }
```

Both state.prop and prop can used, both can changed, so what's the main difference between them?

Comment: Well, if you change `this.prop` nothing happens besides that change in context of React lifecycle, if you use `setState` a re-render will be triggered.

Comment: Change in state will trigger re-render. A component is attached to props and state. So state is something that will make sure you update your component on change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is technically possible to alter state by writing to `this.state` directly, it will not lead to the `Component` *re-rendering* with new data, and generally lead to state *inconsistency*.

Also, to be remember is that `setState` is asynchronous. This `allows` us to have multiple calls to `setState` in a single scope and not trigger the *re-rendering* of the whole tree.

Answer (score -1):

States can be modified by `this.setState`, which will trigger a re-render. But you should not and cannot modify `this.props` within a Component.

States are used within a component, only the component itself is concerned with its value. However, props are received from its parent, the component only reads from it and renders.